# FPDF Can't create a new file

Tags: php, html, kohana, fpdf

I've recently started using FPDF because I need to generate some PDF files for a school project.
All the files are properly included, but when I try to run the code to save the file it gives me the following error:

```
ErrorException [ Warning ]: fopen(pdfs/example1.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I have already checked to make sure the permissions of the selected folder are "read & write" (I'm working on a mac).
Does anyone know what else could be causing this?

Elaboration:
The file does not appear where I want it to be saved, which is why the code also cannot find it, thus returning the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What code are you using? This simple example I threw together works perfectly.

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf17/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Write(5,"Hello, World!\n\n\n");
$pdf->Output('pdf.pdf', 'F');
?>
```

Comment: I kinda found out the problem. I too ran the simple example in a new environment and that worked fine. Apparently I had the wrong paths set for where the file should go. Using APPPATH, this problem is solved. I'll accept your answer as it is pretty much what I used myself to fix my problem.

Comment: Glad to have been of some help.